# What does something-- (minus minus) mean?

Tags: java

what does it mean when there is a `--` or `++` before or after a term like for example `Array[1] = Array[size--];` or `int position = ++size;`

Comment: Read about unary operators: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: I cannot believe this kind of question has a dup.

Comment: People in the answers are leaving something relevant out so I'll mention it here. Where the unary operator is **matters**. If it's before, i.e ++size, then it increments **before** size is used. If it's after, i.e size++, then it increments **after** size is used.

Comment: @NicholasEason that should be in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not an answer to the question though, it's just a fact related to the question. With your logic, Mark should make that link an answer.

Comment: We should not provide link-only answers. If you provide an answer, it should be with your own words and you may refer to content in external links without plagiarism. And your comment seems more like a half-answer and it should be there.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `++` or `--` to the beginning of a variable then whenever your program runs and sees that particular code it will either increment, or decrement your variable by 1 before the rest of that line.

Ex:

```
int num = 20;
System.out.println(--num) // Changes num to 19 first, then prints 19 to the console
```

Alternatively, adding '++' or '--' to the rear of a variable will do the code after everything else.

Ex:

```
int num = 20;
System.out.println(num++) // Prints 20 to the console, then changes num to 21
System.out.println(num) // This would now print 21
```

Answer (score -2):

It mean's that the values are counted up or down

**EDIT**: to correct my failure:
`size++;` is equal to `size = size + 1;` and 
`size--` is equal to `size = size -1;`

Comment: but when it is before the term like ++size?

Comment: Not exactly. Both `(size - 1) == (size--)` and `(size--) == (size - 1)` are false.

Comment: and what does Array[1] = Array[size--]; mean? we put what into array[1]? array[before the last element ]?

Comment: @oughlala Dude, **read the link** Mark provided you in his comment to your OP. You can also just try it yourself and find out. I suggest both.

Comment: @AndyTurner how would they evaluate to false? Are they not both the same value?

Comment: "and `size++;` is equal to `size + 1;`" you probably meant `size = size + 1;`. Same about `--`.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder They're not. E.g. if size was 3, they would be `2 == 3` and `3 == 1`.

Comment: but it's `size--` which would make `size = 2` and `size - 1` would decrease `size at that specific moment and then the change would be lost because it is not stored. `size++` would increase `size` making it `size = 4` and `size + 1` would also increase `size` but just for that moment and would be lost as the change was not stored.